# How to return two arrays using one WHERE statement

Tags: c#, arrays

Is it possible to combine these two statements into one which returns "contains" and "not contains" results?

```
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
int[] numbers = { 4, 5, 6 };

string[] contains =
    (from w in words
     where numbers.Contains(w.Length)
     select w).ToArray();

string[] notContains =
    (from w in words
     where !numbers.Contains(w.Length)
     select w).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
var groups = words.GroupBy(w => numbers.Contains(w.Length));
```

This will return at most two groups: one with the key `false` and one with the key `true`.

### Edit

As [vc 74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446279/vc-74) pointed out in the comments, `numbers.Contains` is an O(n) operation when `numbers` is an array. Converting it to a HashSet instead will make this a constant time operation, which is asymptotically much faster.

So, here's the updated code:

```
var numberHS = new HashSet<int>(numbers);
var groups = words.GroupBy(w => numberHS.Contains(w.Length));
```

Comment: make `numbers` a `HashSet` and you'll get my vote for a solution that scales ;)

Comment: Technically this can also return just one group if all of the words are in one of the groups. Or no groups if `words` is empty.

Comment: _"This will return at most two groups"_ technically this returns just the query since `GroupBy` is using deferred execution. So you're missing the part how OP gets the two `string[]`(contains and notContains).

Comment: Can't test right now, but shouldn't it be `new HashSet<int>(numbers)`?

Comment: @Jimi You are right. I was expecting the `<int>` to be inferred. Doing too much Haskell lately has got me spoiled. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `ToLookup`:

```
var containsLengthLookup = words.ToLookup(w => numbers.Contains(w.Length));
string[] contains = containsLengthLookup[true].ToArray();
string[] notContains = containsLengthLookup[false].ToArray();
```

If one of both is empty (or the source array is empty) you get an empty `string[]`.

There's one difference to `GroupBy`, the lookup is cached. So it's more efficient if you use it multiple times, but the information is just a snapshot. If you modify `words` or `numbers` this isn't reflected in the lookup.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep in mind the difference with GroupBy and ToLookup.